# Growing avocado from seed

Tags: indoors, seedlings, avocado

The first time ever my avocado seed grew a root so when it got really long I planted it and then nothing and I thought I had killed it so while in the dirt I broke off part of the seed just to find out it is fine and green so just wondering is it ok with half a seed?Thanks Karen.

Comment: While life often finds away, I believe this would not be ideal and greatly reduces the chance of the plant fully germinating - you may be better off trying to grow another one from seed.  Some tips - It can take a LONG time to start growing (sometimes months) - keeping the seed emersed in water in a warm (24c + environment) can help.  Sometimes "scarring the seed" can help, eg by sanding off some of the skin or soaking in dilute Hydrogen peroxide can also stimulate growth.   Don't transplant the seed until the plant has a 15cm long stem and leaves - again, this can take a long time.

Comment: You did not describe your sowing method. Many do germinate it in a jar, let the roots develop in water, and then pot it directly in the soil. To their amazement, the tree is shocked and even may die. They don't understand that roots which developed in water for too long have a hard time adapting to soil. Did you grow your seed first in water, or was it soil from the start? Did you keep the rootball intact if you used soil?

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of “is it OK?”   First, is it ever possible?  That depends on what part of the seed remains.  A non-compound seed like avocado has only one epicotyl, or embryo plant.  If what’s left lacks an epicotyl, the seed can never sprout.  On an avocado, the epicotyl looks like the tip of a tube, and depending on the stage of the seed’s maturity may even include tiny yellow/white leaves.  There’s a drawing of the inside of an avocado seed at http://www.inspiredbymygarden.com/germination-of-seeds/.

Second, how good an idea is it to use part of a seed, even if it might be possible?  Not very.  Most of content of an avocado seed, or of most of the grains and other seeds we eat, is starch.  It is food for the baby plant until the new plant has roots and leaves to feed itself.  You’re starting your plant on a starvation diet.  It may or may not survive.

Recommendation:  Eat another one of those delicious fruits and start with a whole seed!

Comment: P.S.  Simply because the inside of a particular seed, in this case avocado, is chemically a starch doesn't make it safe food for humans.  Just so there are no misunderstandings!  Don't eat avocado seeds.

Answer (score 1):

Its definitely got less of a chance of making it now then it did before it was damaged, but if I were a betting man, and I am, id say as long as that tap root isn't damaged, and conditions are ideal, its probably going to make it. 
    Some advice though, dont baby it. If you do, and thats the only reason it survives, your going to have a weak tree. Avocado's are already fairly picky about climate and stress levels. If your just growing it to grow a tree, it will be fine no matter what, I guess, but if your hoping to get fruit off of it, id plant another tree.
      Also, not sure if you're aware, but most avocado farmers trees, are grafted. There are a lot of reasons for that, main one being that they want consistency in thier crop. Another reason is because they can sometimes not fruit, ever. Or sometimes take up to 10 or even 15 years to bear fruit. I have even heard 20 years, but if you graft a branch off of a tree with a particular fruit that you like, onto a solid root stock, that tree will bear fruit in, id say 3 years, tops. Probably quicker in ideal conditions. They also have a weird way that they pollinate and reproduce naturally, which I wont get into because im not sure I grasp it entirely. It has to do with temperature, and the flower functioning as both a male and a female organ, but not at the same time. Heres an article to better explain. 
https://www.agric.wa.gov.au/spring/growing-avocados-flowering-pollination-and-fruit-set
     My point is, It is because of this, that id not only plant about 3 or 4 trees, but id go with grafted trees, not trees from seeds. Id scrap the whole idea of a seed altogether (unless the seed is grown for its root stock). That way you can also get trees proven to be climatized to your local environment. Id also suggest getting a tree that is grafted from a tree that you've tasted the fruit from, and you liked it. When avocados are cross pollinated, you never know what your gonna get, and avocados have quite a range of possible flavors, and not just the ones that you can buy in the store. Those are the ones that taste good, some dont.
      Also, when you see flowers, dont be too excited. It produces a ton of flowers in hopes of attracting pollinators, but most of them wont become fruit. Most of them are strictly an attractant. 
      Avocados are a lot of work but they can be very rewarding. Especially if you love avocados as much as I do. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

My first avocado seed also broke when I planted it. However, I did wait until it was 2-3 inches tall and had a long root before I put it in soil. I planted it in soil that was made for propagating seedlings as well. In addition, I placed the broken half of the seed as close to its original position as I could. I'm not sure if that helped, but it's been over a year and my avocado plant is still growing strong. Looking much more like a mini tree now.

So yeah, my advice would be to keep that one growing, and start a backup seedling just in case :) You need two avocado plants in order for them to actually produce fruit anyways.